# How to add a new row for grid item in material ui?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui, css-grid

I am going to break a line of grid item like this.
[image]
As you can see the image, rest space of grid should be empty.

```
<Grid container spacing={3}
  <Grid item xs={12}>
    "Grid Item xs={12}"
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={4}>
    "Grid Item xs={4}"
  </Grid>
  // empty space
  <Grid item xs={12}>
    "Grid Item xs={12}"
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Should I use inner `grid container`?
Or should I use `display flex`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created new component to solve this problem:

```
export const GridBreak = styled.div`
  width: 100%
`;
```

Then your code would look like:

```
<Grid container spacing={3}>
  <Grid item xs={12}>
    "Grid Item xs={12}"
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={4}>
    "Grid Item xs={4}"
  </Grid>
  <GridBreak />
  <Grid item xs={12}>
    "Grid Item xs={12}"
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I am not sure this is the best way to solve my problem, but it seems a good choice. so check.

Answer (score 13):

I would add `<Box width="100%"/>`:

```
    <Grid container spacing={3}
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        "Grid Item xs={12}"
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={4}>
        "Grid Item xs={4}"
      </Grid>

      <Box width="100%"/> // empty space

      <Grid item xs={12}>
        "Grid Item xs={12}"
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just add the empty grid of xs of 8.
like this:

```
<Grid container spacing={3}
  <Grid item xs={12}>
   "Grid Item xs={12}"
  </Grid>
 <Grid item xs={4}>
  "Grid Item xs={4}"
 </Grid>
 <Grid item xs={8}>
  // empty 
 </Grid>
 <Grid item xs={12}>
  "Grid Item xs={12}"
 </Grid>
```

Comment: Of course, I know it works. What about case of md or another responsive size? Should I use Hidden component as well? Not that!